# Example of "practical" applications of Donaldson Invariants

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, 4-manifolds, topological-quantum-field-theory

I'm studying Donaldson Invariants from chapter 9 of *The wild world of 4-manifolds* by Scorpan, and I'm looking for an example where they're used to distinguish two 4-manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

I know that these invariants are quite hard to compute, and honestly I don't even know where to start in order to find such manifolds; are there any "famous examples" well-known in the literature?

Thank you.

Comment: 'are there any "famous examples" well-known in the literature?' - examples of 4-manifold pairs that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic? If the answer is yes, you can cook up very easy examples. I think what you're interested in are 4-manifold pairs that are both smooth but have different smooth structure. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in smooth 4-manifolds that do not admit smooth structures such that they are diffeomorphic, but that are homeomorphic; in the question when I write manifold I always mean "smooth" manifold.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1883.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the first three pages of [this](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi%3D10.1.1.37.4812%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf) [1] you can find many examples from algebraic geometry that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

[1] 4-manifolds Which are Homeomorphic but not Diffeomorphic by David Gay